# Using sort -k (with 2 fields) as long as -g

Tags: sorting, unix, command-line

Here's what I'm doing

```
sort -k 1,2 -g temp2
```

And am getting

```
hs1 154800000   247249719   3
hs1 27800000    120700000   4
hs1 27800000    124300000   4
hs3 32100000    71800000    9
hs3 32100000    87200000    2
hs3 54400000    74200000    15
hs4 76500000    155100000   20
hs4 76500000    182600000   3
hs4 76500000    88200000    77
hs4 88200000    124000000   2
hs5 58900000    180857866   8
hs5 58900000    76400000    2
hs5 58900000    97300000    4
hs5 76400000    143100000   14
hs5 97300000    147200000   6
hs6 63500000    70000000    73
hs6 63500000    92100000    4
hs6 7000000 29900000    2
hs6 70000000    113900000   70
hs6 70000000    139100000   57
hs6 92100000    113900000   3
```

But I want those larger numbers in the second field below the smaller numbers

For example I want the first three lines to be

```
hs1 27800000    120700000   4
hs1 27800000    124300000   4
hs1 154800000   247249719   3
```

instead of

```
hs1 154800000   247249719   3
hs1 27800000    120700000   4
hs1 27800000    124300000   4
```

Comment: Are the first two characters always `hs`? If not, does `ab2` sort before or after `xy1`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That -k option is a field range.  Use two of them, and include the general numeric option where you need it:

```
% sort -k1,1 -k2,2g temp2
hs1 27800000    120700000   4
hs1 27800000    124300000   4
hs1 154800000   247249719   3
hs3 32100000    71800000    9
hs3 32100000    87200000    2
hs3 54400000    74200000    15
hs4 76500000    155100000   20
hs4 76500000    182600000   3
hs4 76500000    88200000    77
hs4 88200000    124000000   2
hs5 58900000    180857866   8
hs5 58900000    76400000    2
hs5 58900000    97300000    4
hs5 76400000    143100000   14
hs5 97300000    147200000   6
hs6 7000000 29900000    2
hs6 63500000    70000000    73
hs6 63500000    92100000    4
hs6 70000000    113900000   70
hs6 70000000    139100000   57
hs6 92100000    113900000   3
```

Answer (score 2):

`-k 1,2` doesn't mean to sort using two keys, fields 1 and 2. It means to sort using a *single* key that consists of the contents of fields 1 and 2 together. When using numeric sorting, this doesn't work well at all. In fact, you can see using `--debug` that what sort is doing is deciding that values like `hs1 154800000` *aren't valid numbers at all* (because they're not), and ignoring your provided key. What you're seeing is the result of the "fallback sort", which does an alphabetic sort on the whole line, to break ties between lines that have equal values for the keys.

What does work is one of these:

```
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2g temp2
sort -k 1,1.2 -k 1.3,1g -k 2,2g temp2
```

By using multiple `-k` options we get multiple sort keys.

In the first case, `-k 1,1` sorts the first field alphabetically and `-k 2,2g` sorts the second numerically.

In the second case, `-k 1,1.2` sorts alphabetically by the first two characters of the first field; `-k 1.3,1g` sorts numerically by the remainder of the first field, and `-k 2,2g` sorts numerically by the second field.

Both options produce the same output for your sample input, since the first two characters are always `hs` and there are no multiple-digit numbers, but the right choice depends on what you intend to happen in other cases.

Comment: This is a great explanation!